# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter cofiguration not handles requests correctly

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have declared class that implements WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. After successful LOGIN process I am redirecting user to page /main/list which I have declared inside authorizeRequests and bind "v_main" role to this request url. But my declared below configuration returns me to access_denied page which I have declared as accessDeniedPage

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AppSecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;


    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        log.info("configAuthentication");
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        log.info("configure WebSecurity");
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("configure HttpSecurity");    

        http
              .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/main/list")
                .failureUrl("/login?fail=1")
                .and()
             .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/main/**").hasRole("v_role")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
             .logout()
                //.logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
             .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access_denied")
                .and()
             .csrf();
    }
```

**My answer**

What I needed it was change hasRole to hasAuthority.

```
.antMatchers("/main/**").hasAuthority("v_main")
```

Because I am setting role with SimpleGrantedAuthority

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason this problem happens is that the user doesnt have the role
If you print all the roles for this user and ideally one will find that the user doesnt have this role.
You can check with something given below

```
for ( GrantedAuthority ga : SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities() ) {
        log.info("\t\t\t" + ga.getAuthority() + "\t" + request.isUserInRole(ga.getAuthority()));
    }
```

UPDATE: 
In case you are using Spring 4 then in order for hasRole() to work you will have to add prefix ROLE_ to your roles while adding them else you can use hasAuthority().
So `hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')` means the the same as `hasRole('ADMIN')`

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am setting role in my CustomAuthenticationProvider that implements AuthenticationProvider and in its authenticate method I'm setting role to user. BTW I tested your code and it's returning me correct role

Comment: does request.isUserInRole(ga.getAuthority())) true for that role you are checking

Comment: sorry no. I just tested it what does it return. And it returns me role that I have set to user. But as you said isUserInRole not returns true. And what is a problem?

Comment: if you are using Spring 4 there might be a possibility that while adding roles you might have to add prefix ROLE_ for the authorization mapping to work

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I always say that, while explainin your problem you find answer in your own. What I needed to change hasRole to hasAuthority. .hasAuthority("v_role"). Because I am setting role with SimpleGrantedAuthority

Comment: Thought so, if you add ROLE_ prefix your hasRole() will work but if you dont put the prefix then hasAuthority() works